# What scriptural examples exist of people converting to righteousness from overt wickedness on account of a miraculous occurrence (e.g. Paul)?

Tags: soteriology, free-will, miracles, conversion

A brief bit of context (feel free to edit it out if it's not appropriate for the site, but I think it'll help clarify exactly what I'm trying to achieve with this question): I am currently studying the accounts of Paul and Alma in the Bible and Book of Mormon, and was intrigued by the way that their conversion could be viewed, from some perspectives at least, as either "forced" on their recipients, or to be an extra "unfair" blessing that God arbitrarily gave to some ardent unbelievers but not others.  Neither lined up with my conception of God, so I am studying common features in both accounts and pondering why God chose to send divine manifestations to these to individuals.

With that as context, I am interested in finding more data points to compare to, where God took an actively hostile unbeliever, gave them a divine manifestation of His power before they ever displayed faith in Him (so, not them repenting first and then experiencing a miracle afterwards), and then looking at what happened to that person afterwards (did they convert, did they have a particular mission God had prepared them for, etc).

Answers from all denominational perspectives, and from any canonical work or tradition held by a Christian denomination, are welcome.

Comment: 'Answers from all denominational perspectives' is not a possibility on this site. One must scope a question towards a particular group of self-identifying 'Christians' or else one must seek an overview of all possible viewpoints (which involves a large amount of research to adequately fulfil).

Comment: @NigelJ Can't we make this on-topic by scoping it "accounts in canon/traditions of christian denominations". Is a list yes, but completely objective? If just scoped just to Canon, then the list should be manageable? I mean, how big is that, Old Testament, New Testament, some deuterocanonical books, a few denomination specific books at most?

Comment: One cannot scope to 'canon'. Even there, views differ in regard to what 'the canon' is. You mention biblical books in your comment but your question involves something else as well. 'Traditions of Christian denominations' is not definable, being extremely diverse. Hence the requirement of the site (by the Community which uses it and Moderates it) for either definitive scoping or comprehensive overviewing.

Comment: Abram comes immediately to mind.  Depending upon how one understands righteousness (faith) and wickedness (unbelief) a case can be made that every single true believer has just such an experience:  "Flesh and blood has not revealed this to you but my Father in heaven.".  The question then becomes, Can such a revelation be rejected?